# Why does "브금" mean sound track?

Tags: word-origin

I am baffled by this strange word that doesn't show up in the dictionary. "브금" seems to mean sound track. Can someone explain?

Also, does "브금" has any relation to "불금"?

Comment: It must be strange. Because it's a _lazy_, full-syllable word for BackGround Music.

Comment: diacritic of BGM, [BGM] → Korean speaking [브금]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than literally meaning 'soundtrack', it seems to come from a meaning of 'background music'.

'BGM' can be an English abbreviation for BackGround Music, which transliterates to ㅂㄱㅁ→ ㅂㅡㄱㅡㅁ (with 'ㅡ' being the closest thing to a [toneless neutral vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa)) → 브금.

(Possibly it's also a slight play on words in that Background music in Korean is 배경 음악, which could be shortened to ㅂㄱ음 → 브금 - but see Krim's comment below.)

Comment: As a native speaker, I strongly believe it's completely English-originated coinage (BGM -> ㅂㄱㅁ), with default vowel 'ㅡ' insertions (ㅂㄱㅁ -> ㅂ ㅡ ㄱ ㅡ ㅁ).

Comment: @krim You are probably right - I've altered my answer to follow your comment. Hope that's OK. incidentally I don't think BGM is a *commonly* known or used English abbreviation for 'background music' - is 'BGM' (in latin script) commonly used in Korean?

Comment: Yes, BGM (in Latin script as well as its more-proper transliteration 비지엠) is widely in Korea. 브금 is a web colloquial, newly coined within last decade.

Answer (score 2):

'브금' is BGM korean pronounce.
BGM is background music like 'TV , Movie , Game ... etc' 
And '불금' is just 'hot friday' because next day is Saturday and Sunday.
Also '불토' is just 'hot saturday' because next day is Sunday.

'브금' , '불금' don't have relation.

Comment: '불금' is just first letter . '불' -> fire -> hot , '금' -> '금요일' -> 'Friday'